# Creating a scoring algorithm across multiple tables using MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have 3 tables:

**(1) films**

```
id  title
1   AAA
2   BBB
3   CCC
4   DDD
5   EEE
```

**(2) genres**

```
id  film_id genre
1   1       Action
2   1       Comedy
3   1       Horror
4   2       Action
5   2       Comedy
6   3       Action
7   3       Drama
8   4       Sci-Fi
9   4       Drama
10  4       Western
10  5       Romance
10  5       Musical
10  5       Avant-Garde
```

**(3) directors**

```
id  film_id director
1   1       John Smith
2   2       John Smith
3   2       Ann Coates
4   3       Tom Jones
5   4       Ann Coates
6   5       John Smith
```

I'm writing an algorithm that will give me a score based on the closest matches for film #1 - any matching genre scores 5 points, any matching director scores 100 points.

When I compare just two tables - films and genres - the results using this query are as expected:

```
SELECT f1.id as original_film_id, f2.id as matching_film_id, SUM(if(g1.genre = g2.genre,5,0)) as score 
FROM films f1
JOIN films f2
LEFT JOIN genres g1 ON f1.id = g1.film_id
LEFT JOIN genres g2 ON f2.id = g2.film_id
WHERE f1.id = 1 
GROUP BY f2.id
HAVING score > 0
ORDER BY score DESC;
```

**RESULTS:**

```
original_film+id    matching_film_id    score
1                   1                   15
1                   2                   10
1                   3                   5
```

That is, the 3 genres in film #1 match the 3 genres in film#1 (obviously), 2 genres in film #2 and 1 genre in film #3.

However, I don't understand the results when I add in the directors table using this query:

```
SELECT f1.id as original_film_id, f2.id as matching_film_id, 
SUM(if(g1.genre = g2.genre,5,0)) 
+ SUM(IF(d1.director = d2.director,100,0)) as score
FROM films f1
JOIN films f2
LEFT JOIN genres g1 ON f1.id = g1.film_id
LEFT JOIN genres g2 ON f2.id = g2.film_id
LEFT JOIN directors d1 ON f1.id = d1.film_id
LEFT JOIN directors d2 ON f2.id = d2.film_id
WHERE f1.id = 1 
GROUP BY f2.id
HAVING score > 0
ORDER BY score DESC;
```

I was expecting to see these results:

```
original_film_id    matching_film_id    score
1                   1                   115
1                   2                   110
1                   5                   100
1                   3                   5
```

...because film #1 has the same genres and director, film #2 has 2 of the same genres and the same director, film #5 has the same director but no matching genre, etc.

But instead I see these results:

```
original_film_id    matching_film_id    score
1                   1                   915
1                   2                   620
1                   5                   300
1                   3                   5
```

And I simply can't figure out why! All assistance gratefully appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since you matching many rows (genre rows to director rows), you are over counting the scores. You'll be able to see this, if you remove the group by and sum, all the inputs to sum will be enumerated.

You can calculate the scores for genre, director independently, then combine them.

```
select id, film_id, sum(s) as score from (
  select      a.id, c.film_id, sum(5) s
  from        films a
  left join   genres b on(a.id = b.film_id)
  left join   genres c on(b.genre = c.genre)
  where a.id = 1
  group by a.id, c.film_id
  union all
  select      a.id, c.film_id, sum(100) s
  from        films a
  left join   directors b on(a.id = b.film_id)
  left join   directors c on(b.director = c.director)
  where a.id = 1
  group by a.id, c.film_id
) q
group by id, film_id
order by id, score desc
;
```